# Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined . React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React-Native and I was following the steps on the react-native-sqlite-storage on GitHub but I am unfortunately stuck on the transaction and I've tried enablePromises but it still doesn't work. I am kind of at loss on how to proceed.

```
import React from 'react';
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ListItem } from 'react-native';
  
  export default function App() {
  
      let db = SQLite.openDatabase(
        {
          name: 'users',
          createFromLocation: 1,
        },
        successToOpenDB(),
        failToOpenDB()
      );
  
      function successToOpenDB() {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERS', [], (tx, results) => {
            let dataLength = results.row.length;
            alert(dataLength);
          });
        });
      }
  
    function failToOpenDB(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  
    return (
      <>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Title</Text>
  
        </View>

      </>
    );
  };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the success callback successToOpenDB function while making a connection to db and using "db" which is undedined and u are getting error "cannot read property transaction of undefined.So do not pass successToOpenDB funtion as a success callback.

```
errorCB(err) {
  console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
},

successCB() {
  console.log("SQL executed fine");
},

openCB() {
  console.log("Database OPENED");
},

var db = SQLite.openDatabase({
          name: 'users',
          createFromLocation: 1,
        }, openCB, errorCB);
db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Employees a, Departments b WHERE a.department = b.department_id', [], (tx, results) => {
      console.log("Query completed");

      // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.

      var len = results.rows.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let row = results.rows.item(i);
        console.log(`Employee name: ${row.name}, Dept Name: ${row.deptName}`);
      }

      // Alternatively, you can use the non-standard raw method.

      /*
        let rows = results.rows.raw(); // shallow copy of rows Array

        rows.map(row => console.log(`Employee name: ${row.name}, Dept Name: ${row.deptName}`));
      */
    });
});
```

Comment: That deoend upon the usercase where you can to call it 
1. when the app component mount for the first time then you can use useEffect.
2. If you want to do this on a button click then it should work

Comment: Please share the code how you are calling the function and the function

Comment: i have some issue with sqlite, i create the insert fetch delete functions and for some  reason it doesn't work for me. can you help me please ?